# Timed counter in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to set up a counter in P5.js. The counter should sequentially print a number 1 through 10, and there should be 3-second pause in between each print (this process would take a total of 30 seconds).

I am trying to calculate `timeElapsed`, and for some reason it is returning `NaN`.

```
var startTime;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); //set canvas to window width and window height
  background("#dc3787"); //background of pink
  var startTime = millis();
  console.log(startTime);
}

//print i every 3 seconds from 0 - 10

function draw() {
  var timeElapsed = (startTime - millis()); //NaN ?
  console.log(timeElapsed);

  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (timeElapsed % 3000 === 0) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

function windowResized() { //P5 window resize function
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Comment: `NaN` is because you are redeclaring `startTime` variable so its not accessible outside of setup scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created `startTime` a second time by using `var` in `setup()`, so it only exists in the `setup()` scope.

`draw()` is called 30, 60 or 120 times a second, if you don't use `frameRate()`, so to still use it to update every frame just save the time the last number was printet (`lastPrint`) and the number currently displayed (`i`) and calculate the difference each frame.

When the difference is 3000 or more the last frame in whoch the number was printed is at least 3 seconds ago so you can print the next.

```js
var lastPrint;
var i = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); //set canvas to window width and window height
  background("#dc3787"); //background of pink
  lastPrint = millis() - 3000;
}

//print i every 3 seconds from 0 - 10

function draw() {
  var timeElapsed = millis() - lastPrint;
  //console.log(timeElapsed);

  if (timeElapsed > 3000) {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    lastPrint = millis();
  }
}

function windowResized() { //P5 window resize function
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked how accurate the timing is, but you can also lock the frameRate to 60fps and then count up on specific frames equal to 3 seconds using:

```
frameCount%180===0 ? i++ : null;
```

Full code including millis() to check against:

```
let i = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);
  frameRate(60);
}

function draw() {
  background(240);
  fill('black');
  textSize(16);

  frameCount%180===0 ? i++ : null;
  text(i + '\n' + '(millis: ' +millis()/1000 +')',20,30);
}
```